# Jupyter Lab build hangs on jupyterlab_bokeh

Tags: bokeh, jupyter-lab

My Jupyter Lab installation works fine. I just upgraded my nodejs to v10 and completely upgraded my jupyterlab module from pip.

When trying to install `jupyterlab_bokeh` using `jupyter labextension install jupyterlab_bokeh`, the process hangs undefinitely in the build part of the process. It just says

```
Resolving packages...
jupyterlab_bokeh@file:../extensions/jupyterlab_bokeh-0.5.0.tgz
```

Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be the issue with nodejs>9 compatibility. Downgrade to nodejs9 has helped me (on Arch Linux).

See: https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/issues/2061